# ERROR ORA-00904: in simple UNPIVOT query. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, unpivot, ora-00904

Running basic query to UNPIVOT columns to rows and getting "invalid identifier" error. Is there a typo in my code?

Oracle 11G

```
select
   1 c1, 2 c2, 3 c3
FROM
   dual t
UNPIVOT
INCLUDE NULLS (
VALUE
   FOR
      COL
   IN
   (
      c1,c2,c3
   ));
```

Error:

```
ORA-00904: "C3": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:   
*Action:
Error at Line: 533 Column: 13
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please restructure your query like this...

```
with t as (select
   1 c1, 2 c2, 3 c3
FROM
   dual) 
select * from t 
UNPIVOT
INCLUDE NULLS (
VALUE
   FOR
      COL
   IN
   (
      c1,c2,c3
   ));
```